# Port forwarding to docker daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu, port

I have Ubuntu server & my laptop (another network). In my router settings I set port forwarding from my static external ip --> internal ubuntu server ip.

So, to connect to my server I just use `ssh user@external_ip -p 21115` where 21115 binded in router settings. 
Now I run docker daemon at my server via `dockerd -H 0.0.0.0:2375`

What should I do to connect from my laptop to docker daemon?

Comment: I try to work via PyCharm remote docker interpreter. For this I need to run dockerd at my powerful devbox to execute all hard calculations interactive, but use IDE at my laptop from ~anywhere

Comment: **TURN THAT DOCKERD -H OPTION OFF RIGHT NOW.**  _Anyone_ who can reach that port on the server can run _any_ command and edit _any_ file as root with no authentication.  Consider whether the server has been compromised and needs to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same thing as for server, but redirect different port on your router for this second connection.

for example:

"your external IP" and "dst port:2375" --> "your internal IP" and "dst port:2375".

I don't know what are possibilities of yours router, but to keep it safe you should add whitelist to allow this rules for trust IP only